# How the ffmpeg astats crest factor is calculated

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, statistics, compression

I'm scripting a ffmpeg chain process for my work. The aim is normalizing/compressing lot of audio files (mp3's).
It's done in Python and the critical part is the line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Input.mp3" -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k -af acompressor=threshold=-15dB:ratio=5:attack=0.01:release=1000:knee=2,dynaudnorm=g=3:m=2:p=0.95 "Output.mp3"
```

The python script it's complete and working BUT the nature of the audios (voice recordings) are very different so I can't use the same params for all of them.

I make some experimenting with the values of the ffmpeg filter astats and i discovered that the *crest factor* (Standard ratio of peak to RMS level )  gave a good reference to programatically get the better params.

In fact I saw that a recording with a nice dynamic range sound and smooth in shape, get crest values around 9-15 (the compress/normlz params will be somehow conservative). But audios with crest around 22-30 need more aggressive processing.
(All empirically)

Somebody can clarify how the crest values are really calculated? Which are the peaks taken to account? (Why the flat factor is always 0?)
Or if somebody knows how to get a value representing the sound 'smoothness'  will be nice also.

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the crest factor is defined as ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crest_factor)):

[image: Crest factor]

Looking into [*ffmpeg*'s source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_astats.c#L483), we see that the crest factor is defined as:

```
p->sigma_x2 ? FFMAX(-p->nmin, p->nmax) / sqrt(p->sigma_x2 / p->nb_samples) : 1)
```

Setting aside the case `p->sigma_x2 == 0`, we see that:

```
crest_factor = FFMAX(-p->nmin, p->nmax) / sqrt(p->sigma_x2 / p->nb_samples)
```

which matches the formula above, given that:

- `max(- x_min, + x_max)` is equivalent to `abs(x_peak)`
- `p->sigma_x2` designates the sum of squares of audio samples and `p->nb_samples` corresponds to the number of audio samples, so `sqrt(p->sigma_x2 / p->nb_samples)` is the [RMS value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square).

Hope it helps!

Comment: So, if i get right, there's no discrimination in how the peaks are distributed. 
Well it's relatively useful to restraint the loop to find the optimal params.  I think i need more 'intelligent' measure of the curve

Comment: @FranGar Yes, there's no time discrimination/integration period, if that's what you wanted to know. Maybe you could slice your audio files in small chunks and process each of them individually?

Comment: @FranGar Also, you can accept my answer if you found it helpful. Welcome on StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Sorry of course,  but i don't know how to 'accept' the answer, I'm rather new here.
about the slicing:
The main objective is  to find the 'bad peaks' (usually audio bursts/pops, etc) that must been compressed prior to the main dynamic compression. Usually I'll do it visually in Audacity, as they'are spotted relatively easy, but super-time consuming.
Anyway Thanks again

Comment: To accept an answer, just click on the "checkmark" shape to the left of my answer (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). About your compression, you could just use a 2-pass compression. Send your audio in a first agressive compressor which attenuates "bad peaks" and then puts this first compressed audio in another more subtile compressor.

Comment: Yes this is the way, the thing is to adjust the threshold in the first pass to process only these peaks. That's the peak discrimination problem. Now i'm experimenting with both  the 'crest factor' and the  'volumedetect' filter which gives a more fine distribution of peaks. We'll see.